# Arch Linux - Unknown controller version on booting

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, gpu

I recently installed Arch Linux. But Every time I boot, I see this message for few seconds:

```
mmc0: Unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems.
```

After more few seconds I see:

```
radeon 0000:01:00.0: failed VCE resume (-110).
```

And after that, my Arch Linux boot normally.

Also, Arch Linux think I have the AMD/ATI Mars XTX [Radeon HD 8790M] GPU, but I actually have the AMD FirePro W4170M GPU.

Boot log:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KCn2mZbWEmE-8KRvi_AUctjFOr7r4Kxi/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tLmoSCINg--xlIyrO1iQoZDLVk1HFp1A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you post bootlog ? it may be helpful to answer.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KCn2mZbWEmE-8KRvi_AUctjFOr7r4Kxi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: when booted, may you post the output of `dmesg | grep failed` and `dmesg | grep mmc`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tLmoSCINg--xlIyrO1iQoZDLVk1HFp1A/view?usp=sharing